# Why isn't the right side of && operator evaluated?

Tags: java

Small doubt. Why is the output of the following code `1`? Why not `3`?

```
int i = 0;
boolean t = true, f = false, b;
b = (t && ((i++) == 0));
b = (f && ((i+=2) > 0));
System.out.println(i);
```

Answer (score 7):

the Conditional-And operator - `&&` - is short circuit. It doesn't evaluate the right operand if the left operand is false. That's why `((i+=2) > 0)` is never evaluated, and `i` remains 1.

From the [JLS 15.23](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.23):

> The && operator is like & (§15.22.2), but evaluates its right-hand operand only if the value of its left-hand operand is true.

Comment: It did not occur to you that this question is a duplicate?

Comment: @Raedwald I don't have time to search for duplicates of questions asked by other people, so I only close as duplicate if I know a specific question that this is a duplicate of. Otherwise, answering often takes much less time.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the case

```
b = (f && ((i+=2) > 0)); // here f is false
```

Now `false && anything` is `false`. `&&` is short circuit operator so it will not evaluate `((i+=2)` part since left one is `false`. So `i` will remain `1`

Just try to change

```
b = (f && ((i+=2) > 0));
```

To

```
b = (f & ((i+=2) > 0));// non short circuit
```

Now you will get `3`.

That is the two different behavior of `short circuit` and `non short circuit` `AND`.

For more [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18349330/short-circuit-vs-non-short-circuit-operators).

Answer (score 2):

*Agree with the posted answer as `&&` is responsible for this.*

You should note here that your statement `b = (t && ((i++) == 0));` is equivalent to

```
   if(t){
        if(i++==0){
            b=true;
        }
    }
```

and second statement `b = (f && ((i+=2) > 0));` is equivalent to,

```
  if(f==true){
        i=i+2;
        if(i>0){
            b=true;
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
if(p && q){
 // do something
}
```

if `p` is evaluated to be false, the rest of the statement need not be evaluated because of the very definition of `&&`  (`p` AND `q` must be true). If `p` is not true, then the statement cannot possibly be true.